# Homework help - Complexity and running times

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know this is a simple question, but please bear with me. I am given a number of algorithm complexities (log(n), sqrt(n), n, ...) and I need to find the largest size n that that can be solved in a specified time (1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour, ...). The instructions also say "...assuming that the algorithm, to solve the problem takes f(n) microseconds)". Can anyone help me get started please? I already have the solution, I just do not know how to calculate it.

solution for log(n) =>

```
1 second = 2^(10^6)

1 minute = 2^(6 * 10^7)

1 hour = 2^(3.6 * 10^9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a horrible exercise, it's actually very easy. You are given a function `f(n)` and a value for that function. For example, 1 second means 10^6 microseconds. So basically you are asked to solve `n` for the following equations:

- `f(n) = 10^6`, because 10^6us is 1 second
- `f(n) = 60 * 10^6`, because 60 seconds is 1 minute
- `f(n) = 3600 * 10^6`, because 3600 seconds is 1 hour

In your example `f(n)` is `log(n)`. The short answer would be that if you have `f(n) = k`, then to find `n` you need the inverse function of `f`. In other words, `n = f-1(k)`.

For `f(n) = log(n)`, `f-1(n) = 2^n`.

You should now be able to figure the connections yourself and solve your homework for other `f(n)`s.